# Data in loader RemixJs is empty in display

Tags: remix.run

This is simple code with my project on RemixJs.
I try different method but doesn't work.

```
export const loader = async () => {
  return json({ name: "Ryan", date: new Date() });
}

export default function Layout() {
  const data = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem, the data displayed is empty.

Do you have idea?

Comment: That should work. Are you sure you're calling the route? If it's a child route, make sure your parent has an `<Outlet>`

Comment: If you wrote your loader inside a component, it will not run on the server - and hence cannot be accessed through the useLoader hook. You need to write loaders on page files. If you call the useLoader hook inside a component, it will get data from the nearest loader function.